# R mutate ifelse update conditional row with calculated function value

Tags: r, excel, dplyr

I am use R mutate to update a specific (conditional) row with a calculated function, namely, `nrow()`, to update with an add (+) value. I cannot use `apply()` as I need to update only one (1) row for a specific value.

For example, when find row Year==2007 and Month==06, add Incoming.Exam + nrow(df3), so that row will be 698+nrow value.

I get the following error from mutate impl:

> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
>     Column `abberville_LA` must be length 96 (the number of rows) or one, not 4

```
    abberville_LA %>% 
  mutate(abberville_LA, Incoming.Exam = ifelse(abberville_LA$Year == 2007 & abberville_LA$Month == 06, abberville_LA, Incoming.Exam + nrow(abberville_df3), abberville_LA$Incoming.Exam))

    head(abberville_LA, 3)
  Incoming.Exam Year Month    ts_date
1           698 2007     6    2007-06-01
2           NaN 2010     6    2010-06-01
```

Comment: Do not use `$` in `mutate`.

Comment: in other words, just use the field name, eg, Year, Month

Comment: I still get: Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `abberville_LA` must be length 96 (the number of rows) or one, not 4

Comment: abberville_LA %>% 
  mutate(abberville_LA, Incoming.Exam = ifelse(Year == 2007 & Month == 05, Incoming.Exam + nrow(abberville_df3), Incoming.Exam))

Comment: We do not have your data to exactly say what is going on but if you are chaining `abberville_LA %>% ...`  you don't need to add `abberville_LA` again in `mutate` as first argument.

Comment: the date is : head(abberville_LA, 3)
  Incoming.Examinations Year Month    ts_date
1                   698 2007     6 2007-06-01
2                   NaN 2010     6 2010-06-01
3                  1934 2010     6 2010-06-01

Comment: You're using `ifelse` but returning the entire data. What exactly do you want to do? `ifelse` seems inappropriate here.

Comment: so when I chain, yet, mutate() requires and x variable, would I use the following when chaining mutate() ? : abberville_LA %>% 
  mutate(Incoming.Exam = ifelse(Year == 2007 & Month == 05, Incoming.Exam + nrow(abberville_df3), Incoming.Exam))

Comment: I need to select a specific row by condition of date (year, month) and then update set the field Incoming.Exam to be set to Incoming.Exam + nrow(df3)

Comment: IF Year == 2007 & Month == 05, then set Incoming.Exam + nrow(df3). The update is adding nrow to the Incoming.Exam for only 1 row

Comment: @user1857373 Did you get any solution. I'm facing the same issue for my code.

Answer (score 1):

1 .Your question is not clear , So I am trying to apprehend what you want and answering the question

2 .You are using $ in mutate which is not required . Running the below code should solve the issue .

```
abberville_LA %>% 
  mutate(Incoming.Exam = ifelse(Year == '2007' & Month == '06', Incoming.Exam + nrow(abberville_df3),Incoming.Exam))
```

Comment: that exact code returns this error: Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: `as_dictionary()` is defunct as of rlang 0.3.0.
Please use `as_data_pronoun()` instead.

Comment: can you once try replacing "mutate" with "dplyr::mutate"

Comment: you code matches what I also figure out to do based upon earlier recommendations here, but the error for as_dictionary() & as_data_pronoun() still materializes. What or how to use as_data_pronoun() to override this error ?

Comment: OK, I tried "dplyr::mutate --> dplyr::mutate(abberville_LA$Incoming.Exam = ifelse(Year == 2007 & Month == 06, abberville_LA$Incoming.Exam + nrow(df3), abberville_LA$Incoming.Exam)) <-- Error: unexcpted '=' in dplyr::mutate, first argument...

Comment: how else would dplyr::mutate know which data.frame to reference?

Comment: Please copy paste exact code : abberville_LA %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(Incoming.Exam = ifelse(Year == "2007" & Month == "06", Incoming.Exam + nrow(abberville_df3),Incoming.Exam))

Comment: when I remove the $, as this:: dplyr::mutate(Incoming.Exam = ifelse(Year == 2007 & Month == 06, Incoming.Exam + nrow(df3), Incoming.Exam)), then I get Error i ifelse(Year == 2007... object 'Year' not found. Well yeah, that's because the dataframe $ reference was removed... so what am I missing?

Comment: Mukesh Kumar - the result of your code: abberville_LA %>% dplyr::mutate(Incoming.Exam = ifelse(Year == "2007" & Month == "06", Incoming.Exam + nrow(abberville_df3),Incoming.Exam))
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: `as_dictionary()` is defunct as of rlang 0.3.0.
Please use `as_data_pronoun()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

the issue was the library dplyr. I discovered that I had an slightly older version and needed to update to resolve the "Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Evaluation error: as_dictionary() is defunct as of rlang 0.3.0. Please use as_data_pronoun() instead" error message, which was pointing out that another version of dplyr should be utilized. This fixed the code that was provided as answers on this forum.