# Mutate with ifelse in r

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I'm working on a data frame (dim: 10,155 by 33). Few rows & columns of the data frame are

```
  rg[1:3, 1:4]

  REF_NO children age_band  status
1   2148        1    45-50 Partner
2   8099        1    61-65 Partner
3   6611        3    31-35 Partner


> table(rg_age_band)

  18-21   22-25   26-30   31-35   36-40   41-45   45-50   51-55 
     63     456     927    1061    1134    1112    1359    1052 
  55-60   61-65   65-70     71+ Unknown 
   1047     881     598     410      55
```

For variable, age_band, I want to use tidyverse functions separate(), mutate() & chaining operator for following nested operations:

1. separate age_band into two columns a1 & a2
2. replace '71+' in a1 column with '71'
3. Convert columns a1 and a2 to numeric class
4. create a column 'age' which is the avergae of a1 & a2 columnss
5. drop columns a1 and a2

I'm using the following code:

```
library(tidyr); library(dplyr)

rg1=rg %>% 
  separate(age_band, into = c("a1", "a2"), sep="-") %>% 
  mutate(a1 = as.numeric(ifelse(rg$a1=="71+", 71, rg$a1)),
         a2 = as.numeric(a2),
         age = 0.5*(a1+a2)) %>% 
  select(-a1-a2)

Error: Column `a1` must be length 10155 (the number of rows) or one, not 0
```

**Error: Column `a1` must be length 10155 (the number of rows) or one, not 0** Please suggest what can be done.
And when I run the code without '$' in ifelse statement, I get an error **object 'a1' not found** while usually, we don't need '$' while using chaining operator & mutate.
Discussion on [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55662552/r-mutate-ifelse-update-conditional-row-with-calculated-function-value) is not able to give any useful solution.
I tried the peices of code and the problem is with

```
mutate(a1 = as.numeric(ifelse(rg$a1=="71+", 71, rg$a1))
```

also

````
#is producing warning 
Expected 2 pieces. Missing pieces filled with `NA` in 465 rows```
````

**EDIT:** Attaching a [sample data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aDZQeKkhPxDr7ez7_WImOQV3XZ8Z3SGp/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: At the point you call mutate, a1 has not yet been created, so rg$a1 is NULL or length zero; hence the ifelse has length zero.

Comment: It's created by separate() function from tidyr.

Comment: To me it looks like you shouldn't need the `rg$a1` and just try with: `as.numeric(ifelse(rg$a1=="71+", 71, a1))`. There might be something else wrong..

Answer (score 0):

The following code does not produce any errors:

```
rg <- data.frame(REF_NO = c(2148, 8099, 6611), children = c(1,1,3), age_band = c("45-50", "61-65", "71+"))

rg %>% 
  tidyr::separate(age_band, into = c("a1", "a2"), sep="-") %>% 
  mutate(a1 = as.numeric(ifelse(a1=="71+", 71, a1)),
         a2 = as.numeric(a2),
         age = 0.5*(a1+a2)) %>% 
  select(-a1, -a2)
```

Comment: It's working for me too. However, when I'm running my code [with or without '$'] bit by bit [e.g., one statement inside mutate each time], individual sections of code are working. but when running the entire chunk together, I'm getting errors as mentioned. Strange behaviour, I'm unable to figure out.

Comment: Then there might be something else in your data that is causing trouble. 
Could you try running it with a thousand rows at a time: `rg[1:1000, ] %>% ...` and try narrowing it down? Maybe include a larger excerpt of your data in your question?

Comment: I've attached a sample data.

Comment: Using this sample, I still can't reproduce any errors, using the code I provided above. The warnings are there to explain the NA's introduced in your data:
`1: Expected 2 pieces. Missing pieces filled with `NA` in 237 rows [9, 73, 98, 115, 164, 165, 181, 202, 233, 250, 257, 286, 311, 323, 341, 368, 372, 381, 383, 400, ...].` is there to warn you that for "71+" the a2 variable is NA.

Comment: `2: NAs introduced by coercion` is the warning from the `as.numeric` operation performed on a1 if it is "unknown"

Comment: yeah, I understand this warning as in my data I was getting more 'NA's which were corresponding to 71+ or unknown in 'age_band' as expected. However, my code with ifelse inside mutate is behaving strangely as I said before. I sampled my data and attached here

Comment: I tested my approach (see code above) with you sample date. ```rg <- readr::read_csv("~/Downloads/sample.data")```. I cannot reproduce any error, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts @Jeoroen. I'll try again to rectify the issue.